# How to enable logging for spring integration dsl flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

*INFO* log is not getting logged even after enabling info for 
*org.springframework.integration*

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory).destination(topicName))
.log(INFO, m-> “message received for: + ((Order)m.getPayload()).getOrderId())
.handle(orderService)
.get();
```

Comment: You need to show your logging subsystem configuration.

Comment: ` ((Order)m.getPayload()).getOrderId()` - doesn't look like you have a deserialization for that type. Or you just don't show the whole configuration... In case of wrong types there should be an error raised instead of logging. I mean: have you try to just `log()` without any attempts to manipulate with the payload?